# How can I track a table cell?

Tags: c, arrays, strtok, strcmp

I have written a program that compares sentences and finds similar words. The outcome that I should have is the exact cell position in table A of every word that is similar, but I don't know how to do it.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
int i=-1,j=0,q;
char A[1000],B[1000],C[1000][1000]={0},*x,*y;
char c[1]=" ";

    // Just giving the words
printf("\nGive table A:\n");
do
{
    i++;
    A[i]=getchar();
}while(A[i]!='\n');
A[i]='\0';

printf("\n\nGive table B:\n");
i=-1;
do
{
    i++;
    B[i]=getchar();
}while(B[i]!='\n');
B[i]='\0';


    // Compairing every word of the 2 tables (A and B)
y=strtok(B,c);
x=strtok(A,c);
i=0;

while(x!=NULL) 
{
    while(y!=NULL)
    {
        q=strcmp(x,y);
        if(!q)
        {
            // I need to track the cell number of table A here but how?
            printf("%s\n",x);
            j++;
        }
        y=strtok(NULL,c);
    }
    x=strtok(NULL,c);
    if(C[i][0])
    i++;
    j=0;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: So you want to compare A with B and find the words in A that exist in B?

Comment: What do you mean by 'track the cell number'? (Also: `c` should be 2 `char`s: one to hold the nul-terminator as well)

Comment: Define your "similar".

Comment: Yes i want the position of the first letter on table A on each word that is similar in both tables. By "similar" i mean that they have the exact same letters. Thanks for c[1], i will keep it in mind.

Comment: @JimuX Where do you want to store the results?

Comment: Note : `strtok` that it is not possible to use it to mix. use `strtok_r`.

Comment: In table C[1000][1000], what is the difference between strtok and strtok_r?

Comment: @JimuX Why do you need 2d array to store the results?

Comment: Every row is a word and every column is the position position of the word in table A. A word may be written many times so i need many columns. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Note   Each function uses a static variable for parsing the string into tokens. If multiple or simultaneous calls are made to the same function, a high potential for data corruption and inaccurate results exists. Therefore, do not attempt to call the same function simultaneously for different strings and be aware of calling one of these functions from within a loop where another routine may be called that uses the same function. However, calling this function simultaneously from multiple threads does not have undesirable effects.

that's the reason your function failes ,after first loop done

```
x=strtok(NULL,c);
```

will get `x=NULL`,so loop would end.

Comment: Thanks for that, i will try to do as you said. can u tell me a way to know the number of the cell of the first letter that every similar word has in the table?

Comment: oh~maybe you can have an array initialized with 0,when similar word finds out,make the index of array into 1.:)

Comment: But the objective of the exercise is to find the number of the cell of the first letter of each word similar in both tables.